# Spying on recursive Angular controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, jasmine

I have a recursive method that, if a flag is set, will call itself every five seconds. I'm trying to write a test that spies on the method, calls it, waits six seconds and then expects the method to have been called twice. My test fails, as the spy reports the method only being called once (the initial call).

I'm using the [Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), so am attaching these methods to a placeholder for `this`. I suspect there may be an issue with scoping of the controller returned from angular-mocks `$controller()`, but I'm not sure—most people are attaching methods to `$scope`.

Without attaching methods to `$scope`, how can I create a spy to verify that my method has been called twice?

app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp', [
        //...
    ]);

angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = [
    //...
];

function MyController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.callMyself = callMyself;
    vm.flag = false;

    function callMyself () {
        console.log('callMyself');
        if (vm.flag) {
            console.log('callMyself & flag');
            setTimeout(vm.callMyself, 5000);
        }
    }
}
```

appSpec.js:

```
describe('MyController', function () {

    var $scope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('MyApp');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controllerInstance = $controller('MyController', {$scope: $scope});
    }));

    it('should call itself within 6 seconds if flag is true', function (done) {
        controllerInstance.flag = true;
        spyOn(controllerInstance, 'callMyself');
        controllerInstance.callMyself();
        setTimeout(function () {
            expect(controllerInstance.callMyself).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
            done();
        }, 6000);
    }, 7000);
});
```

[Working Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/qu8cbY/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`.and.callThrough()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E) to further execute the function that would call itself:

> By chaining the spy with `and.callThrough`, the spy will still *track all calls to it but in addition it will delegate to the actual implementation*.

```
spyOn(controllerInstance, 'callMyself').and.callThrough();
```

Tested in the plunker - it works.

Comment: I've spent a while looking for how to test recursion, never thought it would be so easy, and other pages/answers recommending huge codes, great contribution